# file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php

I am trying to make an image upoad form. 
The following is the code for the form

```
<table align="center">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return vaidate();" >
<tr><td>
Username:</td><td><input type="text"id="user" name="user"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>
Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="cpass" name="cpass" onchange="validate()" ></td><td> <div id="error"></div></tr>
<tr ><td>
Profile Picture: </td> <td> <input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><td colspan="2">
<input id="submit" align="center" type="submit" > </td>
</form>
```

and the recieving php page is

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){

            $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']));
            $query = 'INSERT INTO users (User,Password,Picure) VALUES ("'.$_POST["user"].'","'.$_POST["pass"].'","'.$imgData.' ")';
            }

        else
        {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO users (User,Password,) VALUES ("'.$_POST["user"].'","'.$_POST["pass"].' ")';
        }
```

but i keep getting the error

> `file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Any solutions please?

On the suggestion of the answers i replaced with the following

```
$imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']["tmp_name"][0]));
```

but now my query wont run. on printing $query i realised there is no ") at the end of the string as concatenated by the function. Any ideas?

the output of echo $query is

```
INSERT INTO users (User,Password,Picure) VALUES ("12312312","1122","ÿØÿà\0JFIF\0\0\0d\0d\0\0ÿì\0Ducky\0\0\0\0\0P\0\0ÿî\0Adobe\0dÀ\0\0\0ÿÛ\0„\0               ÿÀ\0\07\0Î\0ÿÄ\0©\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0   \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0   \0\0\0\0!1  Aa\"Q2q‘BR#bÓ–XrÒ$ð±ñ‚3CcÔ&\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!1AQaq‘¡±Ñ\"2BðÁRá²#3$ÿÚ\0\0\0?\0?gÃ >žâû9ÜFùw2Ã   ÙÜ§!ÃðÊ:úKØ°¨òÉMë+:\0ô•6Oø? 8ÓqSÃ#sÀ$Õ\'¾ŽI$ÀQn½µ;NÝ\\#~¬÷v6òï‰‡ãÏŒuËHîGD‹ßËQ:/¢?œ9éÔ’tÔqç–¿ŽHv±ÀÔèQcnæÈ\\àEðÔ|ÿ\0ñã6œ*ê>*êýA4B@n¦smöÛ;Ïl_C1*9¶jqÍ:JØeKmùµô¤‰ƒõâUýUy7;—ÿ\0²œ    ð7ÿ\0\'¡Ìz¯ê¯ýåÜþzæS¾cùòp~<}UýT³»ZÃl°ß6—ºžýÌ|~<Ë‰rHó}U‡T×›:%?KK|¶žZô¤k©çÆõáÓ¸ŒpZ;v‘ªpŽ+UuUÔ8*­Ö9r<ø”UWPà(UÔ.*ëõp!WP« º‡QU~¡À…ZŽ\"¨Vë?ÇÃ‰B® xŠ¡_QÁT*Ôxq(ZÛ›XTTö—vNˆõÔñ`ùðCÐ]qG]<’xÝÄª     %E–ÇÜ‹»—í-å×îzá@Ÿ9ù0 }²µÁ—\\*C(Rãt¡:$jxÙ&Ü§ò~tºi;ÜÛÍ{{È··}s\'²&î¬,gcþlxÑš‰OPÙeå Gi¡õ¾ÓÚë¯$‚=J(Ù8Ž1JSÌ¦–’=ÑïqA~ÛÜ‹»7®®åTîƒê\'XÉ“Wu•®zhÎ8TÓ)+Œ£¢¢y“áãâKæñ6ûh[Ž©Y½–¦Ž]&«Ý}èvÆU+w\'&ÝÛg¥NÍî\"E*k’ÚÄJø,!qÅ«©kuÑÒžI^½Iæî\'IZQ d5+Ø¿xe}Sg±ïgºû9Ë°‘¿cN­]E¸“}#žº#„5§/‚tâØãíÚ)°x®.º•ßr$}‡wƒœw—Oí»¸v îž;–UIzªÆÒt¹IEœÚPÒÒ’¤©iêJ’ªéQÈØ2Ý¾¬_)¯UzÎèÊv?Zo½¾ÔGzPÙœG©yï°W\0€Èêë\'ÈðHN¼%ü©Þqí)€†6ý£ÉDkyrÈYÞën_Y_¦¯!¿Ÿ*ªºAˆìCSÊÛi´è”€ØHåÆâÞ3mmkAOœ”‡8‘Õi]†Æ2j ÏÝlÓ¬ÈãI–Æ3µm    ™m 2*s%ä) ¨ºÒu^Dp‹œ¹psXÓMpLxèƒ.EÞoo; `B¦ì¾%Iq·R¥PWõ¶ABò£Ó:…òñéKzü¸bÉl˜h<ªª–\\8WÖñ¾á7×ž‹ZI\'™$üx}ncnæÔÓÚ–Iy(qJsÝ}q­±²¤rØåû§ut¹   ÌnâÅôUUHi   n48q’Øy× Qqß¥#D„¬Sáü§*ë ÊÛ=*Ôú_G[ÅÛ|½y0Õ?o­ØÎ7Ÿ·ZÜÓq2ä¹I¾µ…2Ím4Âºu%¤t2”\'’V>g98YÛZ((šÙHé#©)–û‡÷ážm–ãÒí.ÅåI¢³Ä›wí¦#ÊS’ä õ >‡ÓjóÑ:•-  Ôt(_ÉX_ ÀäkÛ²×ma\\ç³=ðïcº½ÎfŽnïL¨ÛŒQlÙîüjšÔ¯Ó…êÕ{+ÐRìÎ• uBÜÐô„«¯!okkvüÇ!Åsµ–i]õ`œÇv^ç8–Ð[ÚíæÎÖÅÜî©ÅÅ¼¾µ ZÉ  )”–T§®J )BO\"µ)*@§eÃ:aºC@tÔ®÷á†=P‰Ë{üî×1šä¹;ÉkDÛ‡ùphÍ[ Á\"2¢4Óó(ðõœ]»¯z\\ûÉ\\~¥÷ÁýÀ»´Á¬šÎíØäì …;W’¥±Ýþ•‡šÀâOÏˆ“‹·ShÈmä­ÇuQ‡Æ½É)2žÕwz+ñˆîžÙ³ «í¹zR“Ç§O‡\\Ìæ\0¸¨Ýs¢žK ¢¯ÊáDþ(¶á±×å:øç‚fÛêÆ]LBïà{Ž·í?u&6ÿ\0“c•ÁF+TºTµÜ,F| ‚©Œ^_/áâ·©pÑÓÖòM‘¨ñÞ™!˜±ÛSÒe:–£´‘ª–·¢R?IÐq¶+:4 M]É¼ÇkžÞÁa(C¶N/YƒGSjÌ°³HE“€Š’d¹ËŒ… ü›ÊéR|4O§>ŒQBë‰m´©Ç^¡ •(ž@\09’uåÆ¼ù$!H×µ¿l¤Æ° ›ÝùÆÎu¸™6åXÓÊ’ûi’òzÄF›Œã^cÈZ•¢‡òútêVRó—‘ÏÛ£AóNíìWf‚\'tX!µÝÀî¾‚<êñ<^õØ•-¼ául$!r1uD©^CŠSZ¨•‘ÔI× œ®’¹Ù•NÐÙ\'ûí·]ï}¹ÒP‚P\"²º~…M¹tø+ñC1œâãÂÎvm±µO¹]ãc«‹º\"ñÞÎå£jû^ÝÜ•%›ÔÎPRHR¥Ü¨@AoN}M¥å8?à<$ã¢õgkt­|±LnŸ²2TC¹xøxxòðùq¸Yµ.žÇv×ûUÚîÒãÏ²Y³´¨NEt•€%\\¨Î(_Í´:–ÿ\0òñ†äeõ.FU¢ÑÚ3d`v\'%•exæŽÛåymÔLs¢Ž©6×SÝK,0Òyu)J? \0sQ \0IŠ¬a{ƒZ*JîçŠœ™ßºæÇà¶Y)´’2‰–²—.ß&x3C|Â:L§R†^‘ ÔêP­><=‡„™ÿ\0ò:”Ó4µüƒ[ôµ3 Ì÷Sî[<¬ŸK·E¶0æ²¶^°¡Žë–Im|•Ñ*[¯yJ\0ò[hJ“â’‡‹Ðð³SßOÙU“‘Â‚ãÌè|ý¿î8 ’“†ÎÆOj~ÜIÉ&µä]·†LÊe$ÛŠ³ÈArjÿ\0†#ÇéÓŒ„îü›Ì2­<º{ø`¯g½FEKRÖ§Q[‹%JZŽ¤¨u$ó:Ÿ5ÔH‘Õí/Úã¿Á)7¸W-dÛäñ‘:«oàÉ0Y… ô…²g:ØóÔú‘¢º´Ò®¥kÓ¾æ^[š¦¶ö\0´¢«±}½m·nxåÖ+µõò«io-¹—d§&-/¸Ûl„¡ÇuPBÒBA\'æI$ð–âêK‡ó’c-ŒQ½TK·öƒúW|· ùH¥Í¯¡0þ6¬Kcõ¤6ÖÝ]Ø=Ë9(£ÈíE¿´â*»röòÎsù%©7Ñ³«Z\\©Ít™s2\'c¶ ?q´u>ç1ô!@¢E}jn/t \'¹2¶œEn]­Ppª¬Í÷pâÖ@nVWŸî-×Kzž§æXXZñ3‘¾1ÚµÈˆ¯éAï¥{Ænkn=´ÛAJT¦=VW|ÂW©IP0àõ$xj=Açò?ð0“ºJv+¼›òoŠ}–íê·3¹ýžÇÖWÆ¾fâå’5A‰S¬×‚þJòzéá·!)ŽžÊyà©ZÇºP…ÑY‡»q\'µISÚÃnW„ö¹_’Kd7a¹÷“ïÖTpDd¦º*U¯Àˆªu:x‡5ã#ÌM¾âƒ \0ñO8øöÅ^©¶{ÅîrY¤Ú}ž‡\'ùö¤å·±­–£!P uâ§dhÅ[àa©t”Ë\0¸rr`ƒVË`.n–îm¶Ý¡$µ˜duÕsADWßH’à> !®µ~®ÜIéÆçt  \\MÜð;TÑši¶i†[K,°„¶ËH%)HÐ$à\0>~MMz­@ÁG»Ý×w2{-ÓÅvb<É0Üj’5ôÚÄ(¥©–s–òû©–e-ëùJœþ.5 lfC™4ðI¹)IvÝc]¤à»¸[»Ÿ¸<í86¹ùÞkzTYÌim¥ªõLÐˆáiZÜRÎ…A   )R‚ƒù$du‰µ>åRÙ¬s¾s@Ÿy{›Ù†²s¶µŠÜiü›)¶‚Œªòž²\\j® Õ)I72Ò·\\RŸi”èÛÊÕ=z9)wËæõ&\'…~[º|MfÖP×T5ö+o]ÝmãÛ=¹Buk.Èà@œ@\'¢\"žI”æƒøWêá½Ì¢8œþ€ª3{ÀêQË÷rÜ¦1˜ÁvžµHbNysë%DkAÑ[J„¨\' i¢TûÍtòÓè?‡Î\"é]!Ð{JmÈ¿kGêˆ/v­¶ƒw{†Ú\\    ÖDªël‚;÷Œ”õ%UÐ5›1*–Ša…§_|hofô¢{û=é]¼{äL]    éJR4J@Ð\0>ŒÓôWâP¢MßåÇû¾Þø¡¯-mØ³@Ð ~á <¥ˆæ§IãmÆ;u»;½Ä¬åØ¤®ïMzfY‘NÆ©ðÉ6n;ŒcófÙTS€€ÓRìÂ%?È¥8˜Í¨Fš uºÝÅßq\\waDy}¬{Rþ“ÇqùÅXNK–ÆT}³‰! ®CÃ¥Ùà+š\\˜>†Ïˆd    KÇŒÏ3{¼úM8ûúÛ· ÞsÑ\'ýå)­]ÇvG!oÌ]$;zù@Ð‰RYŽó=GÀ!—4#ÇNÃsÇbóÉ‚@: É³[€©Ý}»Ü¥Öýå¬ ƒpõPW–§Ñä­m¥d•IÓ‘Ó‡óÅêÆæu+‰ÛtGãqýÙ6£ •?m Ýæ¼Ø§ìÔS`®X²Ÿ¤Ï}kü­žd1ÖTGHRuëˆx9œê>€\'2r\0í­Twòì‡?Ë.2K¹Þe9u›³¬$\0\\zLÉ®•«¥#RJ”­?\0–†ÄÐA&$¸×Ttq.ÆóœWÛßtðÆh“¾»žÄ‚u\"ˆ#±ÆƒU(^œÞ,Â$£ÃÎWFº®3’r-uã]_‘µ`¦­´-·#R½wí«½»÷»¹¦äÜï4Ôk‹)Åà=bÜ…N—Ý\\«)HM6°¦£«^|¼´PFpÜ;Q5‹äqq!uŽË=½²Ù7Nßr2ÜÒŸ-Z¨ªÇãÖ³!¥°ô§[Sî¹ç$£mô\'CûÇÃŽ‡&.#kiÕtµ²1;q+˜wí«¼=ÀoNwº³7c¯‹‘Ìm4unÅ˜µÅ®ŠÊ#Äe])    êKmŽ®žED«ãÇkNV8#Úpýu\\æ±|.¨]Ã±îÃ-»WËól×,Ëª²Û›ê¦i¨UXËÍ±–ø‘/Ì/uqm3§OðŸÇŠü$.Z1ªíiha5%:þç6Ç4Þ]”Í6ÃÉ b–ù›,×Ì¹°C«i0ú1°–‚Ž®´•7áà£áÅ9[ïY…ì!¦…ãìßºzjáÅ ‡åà4\'ñÐøsãAþú?âRÃÆ»¨G_n0¨{u·ØF^¤.E_JÃÍ§ 8 ÇCgOÀ¬ ¨üÏ©^dyqÔ¦±·c@è…¯u^Ý{»Ü¦õd»šîêcu4ÒY‰]ŠÓH-Çb@ŠÐµ”$\'¨¼§:ù¸ueÊÇofÓ]U  ìŸ+Ëª(¾Ý¦ûiäû½ØöëeùíU‰;í•#HC¾¶\\uÅK‡Ï!(mÕA×]9|x‹ÞY³Å± ‚{QmbèÞMQy#öðŽ‰’bÝáö/‡w[ö\\„d.à»‹ŽÄU|,•¸ÂlyPzÔò\"ÌŒ\\dÛ‹R›Z’žµê¨‡\"ûL3oERæÑ³c‘Cž?³fã)þ™{ÓŽGÌyÌ×LyÃóèZÛ_ÍË†ÇŸf>j—ú×u¡Æöc­òZ2ûƒ”dt;ÉÆ¯øz¬µý¼s?ú£=¿Ñ{`þ^Äá;göÓÇûuÝÊ×^èÈÎ$QC˜ÅM3Ôè‚–ß–Êã—Ôè—#^–œP ÎºòÓŠw|»®#1í¥{Wh,NÝZžå¢ï+°Õî›v™Íáî^=ãô±iñºI‘¥8ûHB–ô…:[$¸óª:ƒùBGÃ\\%´{KMI® .¬Ý3ë\\4^{4öíÉ»jÞ·;-Î)2ÖcÐL­¦‡_Co32cŒ…<¥<\0é¥Ärñ+ðåÄò¨¸cAêtEµ‘‰û‰ª+\\þ?¦ þ#C÷mí½›÷½÷û­n%9_{¹‡+\'Æ’ãézdF**h¤¶:ëðáå,Ø\"p&ŸºæÈÊòàh¹Û{?ÝTg˜µ®ãîMCƒVND¼Ž‚¶4¦äNi­1BÝ)Cª.uè*éú´ã¼Üà,! ®Lãˆp.8#›$xqØ‰;QbÅm,ÆŠÊBm´\0”¡ H\0% \0\0‡ÃjšLIº»U„ï>{·[ƒP›œjý ‰,õt<Ë¨=MHŽàÔ¶ëJIPýT’Hf|/i¡ÌŒ7kDÜglþŒ§¶£t¨ï)VJ¢ÁÉÛ‘_5´ë¢[S±’Ó¥#÷ú[×øG(¹Öó´økíJ¤ã]_”ŠÇ½Ÿ·útÄ£#ÏpŠþ¤ù²#=>{á?ŠôŒ$‘øúxöþr-O}>+Èã^s \"uÛ?·†Ìöíe.’ìÉÜX?Tªá¤5œÁ\\+C+#÷Ö·?uIðáMç)-Æ7§Å^‚É‘ã™OãA§‡Ë…tWÈ0­à±»Ÿ:‡{Çi¤(TG…0Ç¨‘êy*_\"1ðùñ(Zíöû¸V¿Òßçð)Z»¼cxqÚ™÷—ËÁ¨©¬h¿>Ê^\'ZÛ,¶Ÿ-J\0ý¼HEBÖâ•û¡›U¬Oºj¼Ž°:¦›­qu\0)M¹¤’P •Ò­„4“ÉZÄŠ„¢^-¼¨·b]ËAM¼ˆ®Nf¬âuÞ¡q™ZqÔ£ÔëÒ•8Nž$q j¾m^éWÙË¦›Ý-L;XuN^J¬{¬KíV2¿-É‹A”ä¥GB½4ãÀ¢¡mÄwÚä[#¹8j¬r0–›!‰Öù‚ž¿7Ìõ==<õ×M9ð)Á%°×³ýÀûÃ{±¨É…Z\'úR¹~Wš ›Qÿ\0©:¥`j•¥C˜\'‰\"Š*ãû}¾ÿ\0î¯ô…ùüB•ó{ß6qç;‰a¦ÙI[Ž+¯Ñ)HÔ“ÿ\0QðIÈuû¡Þò—«I[}EZý]^) QàB®.9Ü93ö6 ]–¨ñ×‰²ãÀaÅ·-•†×&ZÛe¾²žV 5#‰njI-³ÍÛYçû¹˜_ÕWa÷Öÿ\0a®±ÀbXC±™ÐEymN²rÎ$;)BP P|¦‘ù¹%ÊÓí­nKzwf_ÚgHÆ­nº“súµl¸˜m‚‡ªZuRZ“Ô¥¤¨V€q.É5•ž9’U÷·÷Xî-.cÖ0Ñq]_6.KeJ–#Ku/Hhi¢¼¤r?t@ÉÅ,7Nòò’u“&¿3/¾%JÂ¶MF‘Ðóˆ[ËÕCèl)Zj­:A<@RRO¸ªK‹ØŽ 2½­Ný€Å+%Kéu“âú’Ð}ö:„fŸnQ)\'E´Þ©:€e§ª TXÓc‘{|½ ÁæÖMÇÁì`ÐØ\"T·ºß¡u´º©EÀÀB•©ZÊÂG2H©Y\"ƒ€Ö@Èé­ê%EKb7Þn\"^<û%¤ãRa­m†µä„ëÈp9@\\Æ,i·²—!—&´{¼Ÿq£À¦~æµÓV•OKËW”ãÉ©Œ€¥4t+Kg^©\'äW|õoö5d“Çk·Ž ©L&_Rì«”:b—êoDýNt$ô¤ž¥#Eép=øÆ¬-·-´¥E5«ÀKø#v6Pzkhuñm  ø’$²ç¤z*–•:°–Ð¯¯¬ñ à‚ZÎ±ÄÜvÏa*æ¾•+Âã#îr¥0+“äÆi}ÉóRÏçOA_™ÓÒuê#ˆÕ%}œ{s§äÙm¶_ÈÄ±:Úw±LjE•]¢#H-¹êÓ   úâJcå„%ÏŽªO# —Q@NÒ²¼9Ù^V1Ù´rq:Xsaöð¨V¤ªu%„Ÿ]=èèfC«PŠâ‘+¥# áÇ·j7¢‹7´Ü÷/àYcÕy6ªq±øµŒŠác;F]Â 9\"KnÆóS ÇxýIiòž•b»pµ^#‰ØSÔFº·ªÌ(ì!ãr¬¡Uªk­
```

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump` of $_FILES['userfile']? Also that error message is pretty much telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Try $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] instead

Comment: In case you don't understand the error message, it's telling you that `$_FILES['userfile']` is an array, but it needs to be a string.

Comment: @senk, since he's using userfile[] for the input name, it may actually be $_FILES['userfile'][0]['tmp_name'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES['userfile']` is an array, you need to use indexes to access the specific file attributes:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"] - the name of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["type"] - the type of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["size"] - the size in kilobytes of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] - the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the   server
$_FILES["file"]["error"] - the error code resulting from the file upload
```

So use something like this:

```
$imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
```

Comment: that partially solved my problem. could you help me out with the rest?

Comment: sure, please provide more details

Comment: On the suggestion of the answers i replaced with the following

$imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']["tmp_name"][0]));
but now my query wont run. on printing $query i realised there is no ") at the end of the string as concatenated by the function. Any ideas?

Comment: You can see the mysql error using your mysql extension, I'm not sure which you're using. Also check what `echo $query` shows.

Comment: $query shows the query i stored in it plus a lot of gibberish in the end. but what i did notice was the query did not contain a ") to close the query. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could. Please paste the query here if this is not resolved yet.

Comment: copying the query and running the mysql query directly after adding the ") in the end works but without it, its giving an error. So now any idea why its not concatenating as it should?

Comment: i cant paste the entire query here because of the charachter limit but  INSERT INTO users (User,Password,Picure) VALUES ("12312312","1122","*gibberish here*

Comment: Do you really have 'Picure' column? Probably it's mistyped. And without the query text I couldn't help.

Comment: i have edited my orignal question and added the query text there. n Picure is the correct name for the collum as i had mistyped it while creating the table

Comment: try to `var_dump($FILES)` and see what's happening. Is your database table is utf8?

Comment: I guess my syntax had been incorrect. i made a few tweaks here and there and it worked :D... But thanx for all the help